# C# imported DLL Function name case ignore

Tags: c#, winapi, dll, import, dllimport

Is there a way to call "`IsWow64Process`" function from kernel32 capitalized? Like "`ISWOW64PROCESS`"? Or completely lowered like "`iswow64process`"?

And if no, are there any hack-arrounds to achieve this task? Thanks!

Comment: [What is XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Yeah thanks, any suggestions on the problem itself?

Comment: You've not told about your actual problem, instead you're asking for what you thought the solution would be. Please explain what is the actual problem you're trying to solve and why are you forced to do this? That may bring better answers.

Comment: I think it's obvious that my problem is i can't call "ISWOW64PROCESS" but i can call "IsWow64Process" without a problem. I am asking for a way to call this (or any other function of any imported DLL) without having the case sensitive vector in my way :)

Comment: Nope, underlying problem is different is what I believe. Why can't you specify a case sensitive name?

Comment: It isn't that i can't, it's that i am looking for a way arround this problem. I can't believe that's no way to achieve this. Can't be true. I just need to solve this puzzle and google didn't help much..

Comment: The thing is it is not clear why you want to call `ISWOW64PROCESS` rather than `IsWow64Process`. What is the underlying problem that you think you need to type the call to `IsWow64Process` in upper case in your source code.

Comment: Guys the question isn't why, the question is how!

Comment: why are you refusing to help them help you?

Comment: Its case sensitive, as you say.  What if SomeApi and SomeAPI were both exported, which is correct? If you do not know the case at runtime you would need to dynamically examine the exports of the target dll and look for a match then dynamically call the exported function.

Comment: @SlothGR "Guys the question isn't why, the question is how!" In many Q&A circles, this is an unhealthy way of thinking. The people who are here *want* to answer your question, but without an explanation they can only **assume** you either have a misconception as to how the technology in your question works or want to do something that is wrong for other reasons. It can be frustrating when you **know** you're looking for **this thing**; but it may very well be that "this thing" is the wrong answer! [Related](http://bit.ly/13raaPF) [2](http://bit.ly/1t1mi6t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# is a case sensitive language, but you can define the pinvoke call any way you like, you just need to be consistent.  You can map the EntryPoint in your PInvoke call and define the function to be all uppercase like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, EntryPoint = "IsWow64Process")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ISWOW64PROCESS([In] IntPtr processHandle,
     [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] out bool wow64Process);

private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool is64;

    ISWOW64PROCESS(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out is64);

    MessageBox.Show(is64.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [DllImportAttribute.EntryPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint(v=vs.110).aspx) field allows you to specify the real name of the imported function.

Directly from the example at that link are two lines that show how you can rename the MessageBox function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "MessageBox")]
public static extern int MyNewMessageBoxMethod(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, uint type);
```